# INJECT: NoMethodError: undefined method `<<' for :one:Symbol

Tags: arrays, ruby

How do I use inject properly and eliminate my error?

I am trying to create an array. This is an example, and I know there are better solutions to getting the end result, but I am trying to understand inject better.

```
a = [:one,:two,:three]  # => [:one, :two, :three]

a.inject do |sum = [], v|  # => [:one, :two, :three]
  sum << v   if v != :one  # ~> NoMethodError: undefined method `<<' for :one:Symbol\nDid you mean?  <
end
```

The intent is to add items of the array called `sum`, which starts as an empty array, adds items if the item is not equal to :one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the initial value of sum as an argument. In this case, the initial value needs to be an empty array.  Again, you need to ensure that sum is the last evaluated line in the block.

You NEED to pass an initial value because if you don't, the first value of the collection `:one` is automatically assigned to `sum`, so `sum <<` will fail (symbols don't support `<<`)

In summary... if no default value, `:one` is assigned to sum and the block only evaluates for `[:two, :three]`  with an initial value, the block evaluates for every member of the collection.

```
a = [:one,:two,:three]  # => [:one, :two, :three]

a.inject([]) do |sum, v|  
  sum << v   if v != :one
  sum 
end
```

Comment: Wonderful explanation, I was setting the initial value in the wrong place. thank you

Comment: No problem!  If you're happy with my answer, feel free to accept it. I get bonus points that I can trade in for fruit... or maybe not, but I still get bonus points.

Comment: It always makes me wait a few minutes until I can accept an answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to return `sum` after `if` condition

```
a = [:one,:two,:three]  # => [:one, :two, :three]

a.inject([]) do |sum, v|  # => [:one, :two, :three]
  sum << v   if v != :one
  sum 
end
```

Comment: thank you ,but it does not solve this.. NoMethodError: undefined method `<<' for :one:Symbol

Comment: yeah, I edited my answer. Didn't noticed some syntax errors from the first glance. Anyway, you already got right answer! Good luck!